# How to insert dockerised cron process in a docker-compose built LEMP stack?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, cron, docker-compose

I have a LEMP stack which is built by this docker-compose file:

```
cadvisor:
  image: google/cadvisor:latest
  container_name: lemp_cadvisor
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes:
    - "/:/rootfs:ro"
    - "/var/run:/var/run:rw"
    - "/sys:/sys:ro"
    - "/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro"
base:
  build: ./base
  container_name: lemp_base
  volumes:
    - /home/core/server-lemp/www/:/var/www/:rw
phpmyadmin:
  build: ./phpmyadmin
  container_name: lemp_phpmyadmin
  links:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/www/phpmyadmin
    - ./phpmyadmin/var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:/var/www/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php:rw
mariadb:
  build: ./mariadb
  container_name: lemp_mariadb
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd
  links:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/run/mysqld
    - /home/core/server-lemp/mariadb/:/var/lib/mysql/:rw
    - ./mariadb/etc/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf:ro
ffmpeg:
  build: ./ffmpeg
  container_name: lemp_ffmpeg
  links:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /usr/ffmpeg
cron:
  build: ./cron
  container_name: lemp_cron
  links:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /etc/cron.weekly
    - /etc/cron.d
    - /etc/cron.hourly
    - /etc/cron.daily
    - /etc/cron.monthly
php:
  build: ./php
  container_name: lemp_php
  links:
    - base
  volumes:
    - /var/run/php-fpm
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf:/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.conf:ro
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php.ini:/usr/local/php7/etc/php.ini:ro
    - ./php/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:/usr/local/php7/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf:ro
  volumes_from:
    - base
    - phpmyadmin
    - mariadb
    - ffmpeg
    - cron
nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  container_name: lemp_nginx
  links:
    - base
  ports:
    - "80:80"
    - "443:443"
  volumes:
    - /var/cache/nginx
    - ./nginx/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
  volumes_from:
    - php
```

My `./cron/Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# Lanti/lempCron
#
# VERSION               1.0.0

FROM lemp_base:latest
MAINTAINER XY <info@domain.com>
LABEL Description="Cron" Vendor="XY" Version="1.0"

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y dist-upgrade \
    && apt-get -y install \
        cron

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

When in a Wordpress install I inspecting running cron jobs with WP Crontrol plugin, I got the following error message:

```
There was a problem spawning a call to the WP-Cron system on your site.
This means WP-Cron events on your site may not work. The problem was:
Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

I assume because of the same error that causing this, the Cache Purge option in the Nginx-helper plugin also not working.

Comment: WP-Cron is not actually using *cron*, it's a [simple tool that executes scripts if a visitor views the website](https://www.lucasrolff.com/wordpress/why-wp-cron-sucks/). If your web server listening on `0.0.0.0:80` (and not only `127.0.0.1:80`?

Comment: In nginx.conf if I define these IP addresses for server_name: `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `10.0.2.2`, the error message always stays. Should I try `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: I changed it to `0.0.0.0`. The error message is still appears.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is presumably running in your 'php' container, and the "wp-cron" function is presumably working there. Although it is "cron-like", it is actually part of Wordpress.

You have defined no [ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) for your `php' container, so it appears that you need to update your [Docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) so that wp-contain can access port 80 on the correct host.

Comment: PHP is communicating with Nginx container through socket at `/var/run/php-fpm` which is a shared volume to nginx container in favour of FPM/FastCGI. Do I have to create a port in this case too?

Comment: So probably good idea to place cron in the php image and start both processes (php, cron) with supervisord?

Comment: Personally, I find this solution overly complicated and would either skip using containers or would use the simpler `systemd-nspawn` containers available on all systems with `systemd`. In particular, there's the [network-veth](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn#use_host_networking) option allows the guest OSes to share networking with the host, saving you managing inter-containing networking, which is the root of the problem here. `systemd-nspawn` still gives you process isolation and chroot'ed environments.

Comment: Thank You the help and advices! Looks like I solved it. I moved cron into php container and fire up both processes with supervisord. Next, I removed `links` from the docker-compose file (it will be deprecated in the future, plus not working with `host` cmd) and I ordered my containers with `volumes_from` and I placed this line at every container in the docker-compose file: `net: "host"`. This way the docker containers using the host's networking, not bridged. I also followed this tutorial linked by @thaJeztah: https://www.lucasrolff.com/wordpress/why-wp-cron-sucks/ Now the cron job came alive.

Comment: But with this new stack I have a new problem: something completely deleting the webserver files at `/var/www`. Any tips how I can find out what doing this?